# C: allocation limits

Tags: c, memory-management, configuration

I am trying to allocate ~ 1GB , but when I check the pointer address it's a negative number. Could this be a configuration limit I am hitting somewhere.

- goal to allocate ~1GB
- limit of ~0.7GB ([struct]48 * 16890)
- 1.5GB free memory
- no large amounts of memory were allocated before this.
- using fedora linux.
- no compiler errors

Comment: LOL, are you serious?  Never concern yourself with the "sign" of a pointer, it is not an integer.  If malloc() returns non-zero, it worked.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that a pointer address can be a negative number - you must be on a very unusual hardware platform ;-) Although it can certainly be *converted to* a signed int on any platform.

Comment: Yeah, can you expand on why you think it's not working?  Pointers are unsigned, and it will return NULL if the malloc failed.

Comment: How are you checking the pointer? Does your program work?

Comment: I run it so I am not building on top of errors ,but it is no where near complete.

Comment: I guessed it was just a problem, since I never noticed one before in a positive sense. When I would fix a problem I guess coincidently the negative integer would go away. So i associated it with bad things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't test for a pointer's "sign", it's irrelevant. The only invalid pointer that `malloc` will return is the null pointer. If it returned something else, you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

> but when I check the pointer address it's a negative number

That's not possible. What you might see is interpretation of the address as a signed integer.

There is no limit embedded in C itself. The allocations are limited by the data type used for requested block size and addressing capability of the operating system.

During runtime the request will fail (`malloc()` returning `NULL`) if there is not a continuous block of free memory of the requested size.